# Variance Of Uniform Distribution After Log Transformation

Tags: variance, random-variable, link-function

Suppose I have a random variable $X \sim Unif(0.61, 0.79)$ and now I'm interested in the mean and variance of $Y \sim \log X$.  I can easily calculate the mean using the equation,
$$
E(g(X)) = \int f_X(x)g(x)\,dx
$$
where $f_X$ is the pdf of $X$.  For my case this boils down to,
$$
E(g(X))=\dfrac{1}{0.79-0.61} \Big[F(0.79)-F(0.61)\Big]
$$
where $F(x) = x\log(x)-x$.  Now I'm not sure how to analytically derive the variance.  I can approximate it with,
$$
Var(g(X)) \approx \left(\dfrac{1}{\mu}\right)^2Var(X)
$$
where $\mu = E(X)$.  I was just wondering if there was an analytical solution that was better than the approximation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: 
$$\mbox{Var(g(X))}=E[g^2(X)]-E[g(X)]^2$$

$$\int \log^2(x)dx=(x\log(x)-x)\log(x)-\int [\log(x)-1]dx=...$$

Comment: Thanks! I just needed that first formula.  So $Var(g(x)) = \dfrac{1}{0.79-0.61}\Big[F(0.79) - F(0.61) \Big] - E(g(x))^2$, where $F(x) = x \log(x)^2 - 2x\log(x) + 2x$.  If someone could double check me, I got an answer of 0.005553132.

Comment: @user13317: yep: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BLog%5Bx%5D%5E2%2F(0.79-0.61),%7Bx,0.61,0.79%7D%5D-Integrate%5BLog%5Bx%5D%2F(0.79-0.61),%7Bx,0.61,0.79%7D%5D%5E2