# Variance of the logarithm of the product of two random variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance

I need to calculate the variance of the following product on the log scale,
$$
    Z \sim \alpha \beta X Y 
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both scalars and $X \sim LN(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim U(a, b)$.  $X$ and $Y$ are independent of each other.  What I'm interested in is,
$$
Var(\log Z)
$$
On the log scale the scalars will not affect the variance, so is this correct?
$$
Var(\log Z) = Var(\log(XY)) = Var(\log(X) + \log(Y)) = Var(\log X) + Var(\log Y)
$$
I know $\sigma^2$, which is $Var(\log X)$, and I can calculate $Var(\log Y)$ form [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291627/variance-of-uniform-distribution-after-log-transformation/291630?noredirect=1#comment556327_291630).

Is this approach valid?

Comment: You may need to assume that parameter $a>0$ (currently not stated). $$Var(\log Y) = 1-\frac{a b (\log (b)-\log (a))^2}{(b-a)^2}$$

Comment: You are correct, that's the way to go.